# While loop inside for loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to using a while loop inside a for loop in Matlab. The while loop will repeat the same action until it satifies some criteria. The outcome from the while loop is one iteration in the for loop. I am having a problem to get that correctly.

```
n=100;
for i=1:n
    while b<0.5
        x(i)=rand;
        b=x(i);
    end
end
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrongly.
Thanks

Comment: what is wrong with the code? what exactly is the problem?

Comment: BTW, it is best [not to use `i` as a variable name in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)

Comment: you probably have to initialize `b` before first calling the `while`-statement

Comment: I tried to initialise b but that doesnt work. I am trying to get a vector of x values with size(1x100) all values more than 0.5. the x value is randomly generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the example you showed, you have to initialize `b` or the `while`-statement cannot be evaluated when it is first called.
Do it inside the `for`-loop to avoid false positives after the first `for`-iteration:

```
n=100;
for ii=1:n
    b = 0;
    while b<0.5
        x(ii)=rand;
        b=x(ii);
    end
end
```

Or, without `b`:

```
n=100;
x = zeros(1,100);
for ii=1:n
    while x(ii)<0.5
        x(ii)=rand;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Approach the problem differently.  There's no need to try again if `rand` doesn't give you the value you want.  Just scale the result of `rand` to be in the range you want.  This should do it:

```
x = 0.5 + 0.5*rand(1, 100);
```

Comment: I like your approach however Schorsch's approach is more relevant to my problem.

Comment: @LindaRabady Why is it more relevant? Please add more details so that it can be answered properly then. If you're re-generating a random number using a loop to force it to be within a specific range, something in your initial approach is probably wrong.

Comment: @EitanT maybe the `rand` was just an example and the question really was about how to set up the statement so that it can be evaluated the very first time the `while`-statement is called. But that's just guesswork.

Comment: @Schorsch Hence my plead for more details :)

Comment: Thanks all, sorry for being late in my reply. yes the rand was just an example but the idea is excellent. I can use it somewhere else.